# Running non Tkinter code along side Tkinter code

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I am writing a server/client encrypted chat service and have decided to spruce up my server code using Tkinter to display connected addresses. However, because of the Tkinter aspect, it's all that runs. I was wondering if I could run both simultaneously. I am already using .after() to update the client list every 5 seconds. I am already using threading to manage connections. Is threading a valid way to run both easily?

My two main piece of code that need running here are:

```
window.mainloop()
```

and

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    SERVER.listen(7)
    client_thread = Thread(target=accept_connections)
    client_thread.start()
    client_thread.join()
    SERVER.close()
```

Comment: i wont be able to tell but here is a tutorial for [threading](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IEEhzQoKtQU) with real life example and tutorial for [multiprocessing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fKl2JW_qrso) with real life example.

Comment: As long a the threaded code's excution doesn't take too long and starts to  interfere with the `mainloop()`, it should be OK.

Comment: You can put `window.mainloop()` between `client_thread.start()` and `client_thread.join()`.